# Method lookup in C

Tags: c, lookup

I'm trying to make a game in C, using OOP. I ran into the problem of being able to look up methods in superclasses.

At the moment, my objects look more or less like this:

```
typedef unsigned int PTR

struct Object{
    PTR super;
    PTR (method1 (PTR self, ...));
    .
    .
    .
    PTR (methodN (PTR self, ...));
}
```

I want to look up a method, and if it's not found in an object, to iteratively look for it in it's super, it's super's super, etc, and return 0 (method not found) if `super == NULL` at some point.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: @user2357112 I'm using some of the practices I learnt from MRI: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/include/ruby/ruby.h (look for VALUE).

Comment: @user2357112 Why do you think that's bad?

Comment: *How could I achieve this?* Use an actual OO language such as C++ and have it done for you?

Comment: C is not object oriented. there is no object system. there is barely a type system! it is all numbers. go get a java compiler.

Comment: @csTroubled: Well, for one thing, `PTR` isn't a pointer, and it's quite likely too small to hold a pointer.

Comment: @cat: Nonsense! OP might go too far here, but you can very well OOP in C. Just see most larger projects, e.g. the Linux kernel! There are more than the C++/Java inheritance approach for OOP; others might be more suitable for a C implementation. Anyway, using Java is certainly one of the worst recommendations. You don't even know there is a bytecode interpreter on the target!

Comment: While OOP in C is qell established practice, there is a point one really should stop and use a language which supports inheritance in the grammar directly. C might be better suited for lean OOP like component-based OOP. Your approach will result in macro-hell and/or redundant code. You also likely will have to massively typecast, which inhibits the compiler from type-checking. Whatever you think: you do not want this!

Comment: For an excellent article/tutorial on incomplete datatypes, encapsulation, data-hiding, dynamic linkage/late binding, opaque pointers and object oriented approaches to dynamic data-structures, see [**Object Oriented Programming in ANSI-C**](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf). While it is written at, and requires, a fairly in-depth knowledge of C, it is well worth the effort requierd to digest the material. It covers a number of topics not included in most C books or tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it with a simple loop:

```
typedef PTR (*MPTR)();

MPTR lookup_method1(struct Object obj) {
    MPTR res;
    do {
        res = obj->method1;
        obj = obj->super;
    } while (!res && obj);
    return res;
}
```

The loop walks up the links of your inheritance hierarchy until the appropriate method is found.

However, your approach is rather slow. You should walk your hierarchy upfront, and set all `NULL`s to the pointer from the parent. This way you'd have a quick look-up; if the pointer is `NULL`, there is no implementation.

Comment: I'm sorry, I believe I was not clear enough, I want to be able to look for any method, not having a function to find each method (I wouldn't like  to have a `lookup_method1,...,lookup_methodN`, for every method in the entire game). But rather a function that let me do something along the likes of `call("method", obj)`.

Comment: @csTroubled C lacks reflection facilities, so you need some way to identify methods beyond their field names. Once you have that in place (e.g. an array with an index) you should be able to make a function that uses that mechanism to make a single function for all look-ups.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: And en passant this will eliminate type-checking by the compiler, thus removing any help from that side. Sound like a very bad idea, even more for an unexperienced user. And I will not even think about debugging resp. testing.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is not to search the super class for an implementation, but rather include the method table of the super class in the derived class. Saves you a lot of hassle:

```
typedef struct SUPER {
   int attribute1;
   int attribute2;
   int (*method1)(struct SUPER *self, int arg1, int arg2);
   int (*method2)(struct SUPER *self, char *ptr);
} SuperClass_t;

typedef struct SUB {
   struct SUPER superclass;
   int (*method3)(struct SUB *self);
} SubClass_t;
```

Finding the superclass implementation in a derived class is dead easy:

```
// Call superclass method
void subClassMethod (SubClass_t *self, char *ptr){
   self->superclass->method2 (&(self->superclass), ptr);
}
```

If you want it even more close to "real" OOP languages, don't store the method pointers in the instances, but rather have an indirection to a VMT shared by all instances that actually holds the method pointers. Adds another indirection when calling a method, but saves you a lot of initialisation code in the constructor as you need do it only the first time you instantiate an instance of a specific class.&